# Getting Facebook other user profile image url using mobile number only using API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Getting Facebook other user profile image url without his/her login OR FBID, **just using Mobile Number.**

Is that possible using API of Facebook?

If no, is there anything mentioned in documentation of Facebook API DOC?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Rule of thumb: Without authorization, you cannot get any data.** Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, so the only way to get any data (even if it´s only the profile image) is to authorize that user.

Btw, you cannot even get the mobile number with authorization, so the other way around is obviously not possible too.

Comment: Alright.

And there is any way to find Facebook details of any user using mobile number only using any Facebook API ?

Comment: no, of course not. you can´t match mobile numbers, read the last paragraph of my answer.